# Using Iterator for TreeSet

Tags: java, collections, iterator, treeset

I know that a TreeSet is ordered. But does that guarantee that every time I create an iterator, it is going to go through the elements of the collection in the same order (provided that I am not adding/removing any elements)?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#iterator%28%29

Comment: See :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Answer (score 9):

Yes, as the Javadoc states :

> Iterator java.util.TreeSet.iterator()
>
> Returns an iterator over the elements in this set **in ascending order**.
>
> Specified by: iterator() in NavigableSet, iterator() in Set,
>   Overrides: iterator() in AbstractCollection Returns: an iterator over
>   the elements in this set **in ascending order**